# React map - returning value

Tags: javascript, reactjs

how can I return just one element from an array from another file
where element (let say it's `"2"`) is equal to id in that file

```
import { AnotherFile } from './AnotherFile'

const element = exFunc(element)

const exFunc = (val) => {
      {AnotherFile.map((data) =>
         data.id === parseInt(val) &&
         return {data}
      )} 
   }
```

This is the other file with data:

```
export const AnotherFile = [
   {
      id: 1,
      text: 'Num 1',
   },
   {
      id: 2,
      text: 'Num 2',
   },
   {
      id: 3,
      text: 'Num 3',
   }
]
```

Ps. More exactly i need a "text" value

```
alert("The text is: " + <>text value of data with id=2 from AnotherFile<>)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**It doesn't work with `&&` like that in the function, you would need to do a proper logic block:**

```
const exFunc = (val) => {
  AnotherFile.map((data) => {
    if (data.id === parseInt(val)) return { data };
  });
};
```

Comment: Inside the function ```exFun``` it works but when I try to access it in the original one for example ```console.log(element)``` it shows undefined

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the filter method for this. Please note the "?" operator to be sure that you don't try to access an item that does not exist

```
const exFunc = (val) => AnotherFile.filter((v) => v.id === val)[0]?.text;

console.log(exFunc(2));
```

Answer (score 0):

This part :

```
data.id === parseInt(val) &&
         return {data}
```

don't work inside a function

Try this :

```
if(data.id === parseInt(val)) return {data}
```